# How to connect a LookupTable on a Grid with VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I’m trying to connect a LookupTable on a Grid(like one from examples). I have seen some tutorial and I have done what was in there, but it still not working.

I have defined a new lookup table like this

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> lut =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();

lut->SetNumberOfTableValues(x.size() * y.size());
lut->SetTableValue(0, colors->GetColor4d("Orange").GetData());
lut->Build();
```

and connected with the grid through the mapper, like this

```
rgridMapper->SetLookupTable(lut);
rgridMapper->SetUseLookupTableScalarRange(true);
rgridMapper->SetScalarModeToUsePointData();
```

Anyway it’s still not working. Why is it happening? How could I set a lookup table on a grid? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use vtk python for programing,

My idea is that

You need to use `rgrigdMapper.SetScalarRange(minValue,maxValue)`

Here, the min and max value are the lower and upper limitation of the points color data. Usually, this data is set by `vtkFloatArray` and deliver to points by `vtkPolyData.GetPointData().SetScalars(points)`